# uWSGI Virtualhost mode with touch-reload

Tags: nginx, python, django, wsgi, uwsgi

So far I have been experimenting with [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki) to replace a lot of kludgy server code that builds and does setup for Python wsgi applications under supervise. I am running dozens of these small projects (Django, Flask, other) at once.

Currently I am running in [Virtualhost](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/VirtualHosting) mode and I allow NGINX to basically invoke applications at will. However, it seems the reload feature "touch-reload" is meant for a specific file.

Is there a way to use "touch-reload" to monitor the module that is running either by specifying it per site or automatically? Or is there a way to allow touch-reload to be configured per application?

I have also looked at [emperor](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Emperor) mode, which seems like it could be a slightly less awesome substitute but I am not sure if my use case would cause dozens if not hundreds of processes to spawn. I like the virtualhost mode because it essentially shares a pool of workers over all of the applications, this seems most efficient to me.

**Current Configs:**

uWSGI

```
<uwsgi>
    <vhost-host/>
    <master/>
    <gid>www-data</gid>
    <uid>www-data</uid>
    <catch-exceptions/>
    <socket>/var/tmp/uwsgi.sock</socket>
    <chmod-socket/>
    <idle>300</idle>
    <processes>6</processes>
    <no-orphans/>
    <enable-threads/>
    <reload-mercy>5</reload-mercy>
    <threads>10</threads>
    <no-default-app/>
    <touch-reload/>
    <!-- <reload-on-rss>128</reload-on-rss> Reload at 128MB of RSS (memory usage) -->
</uwsgi>
```

---

Update:

After doing some research about how uWSGI handles shutting down idle workers, I think I will need the emperor mode after all.

What I am trying to do is let seldom used applications take no resources and oft used applications take more resources. I am trying to do that while maintaining a hosting deployment as simple as PHP-FPM. The virtual mode achieves this but seems to shut down all workers only after all applications have been idle, which isn't useful if any app receives a steady stream of traffic. I would love to be corrected on this issue if it's untrue.

The downside to going with emperor mode is that I will have to make socket files and config files for each application (blech!). I would still like to know if it's possible to implement per application reloading as mentioned above though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should ask it in the official mailing-list, all of your statements are true, so you should try to ask for an improvement in the list.

Comment: Unfortunate, but I will refer the mailing list here. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running multiple apps, you probably want `emperor` mode which superceded `vhost` mode for most use cases (including what you describe).

For dynamically scaling workers across all the apps, you have several options.

The simplest is probably [uWSGI's `cheaper` subsystem](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Cheaper.html). It provides very fine-grained controls for setting minimum and maximum number of workers for each app, as well as enforcing a global memory limit across all apps (so you don't have a complete blowup if all apps spike at once.)

If you want a single pool of workers that are shared across all apps (rather than spinning workers up/down for each app), then the slightly more complex solution is  Emperor + Broodlord + Zergs. The best place to start is probably the official docs on Broodlord mode: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Broodlord.html